# Creating firebase rule to authorize write permission to owner and read permission to provided email

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have data structure like following, which I am ready to re-structure if required to achieve my goal.
I want owner to be able to read or write and user with mail Id in "sharedWithEmail" key to be able to read the list.

```
"root_node" : {
  "firebaseUid1" : {
    "-Kb5L4zvfgscWdDC9utF" : {
      "data1" : 1,
      "data2" : "abcd",
      "sharedWithEmail" : "abc@gmail.com",
      "userMail" : "user1@gmail.com"
    },
    "-Kb5sddvfgscWdDC9utF" : {
      "data1" : 2,
      "data2" : "abcd",
      "sharedWithEmail" : "123@gmail.com",
      "userMail" : "user1@gmail.com"
    },
    "-Kb5sddvfgscWdDC9utF" : {
      "data1" : 3,
      "data2" : "abcd",
      "sharedWithEmail" : "blabla@gmail.com",
      "userMail" : "user1@gmail.com"
    }
  }
  {
  "firebaseUid2" : {
    "-Kb5L4zvfgscWdDC9utF" : {
      "data1" : 1,
      "data2" : "abcd",
      "sharedWithEmail" : "1@gmail.com",
      "userMail" : "user2@gmail.com"
    },
    "-Kb5sddvfgscWdDC9utF" : {
      "data1" : 2,
      "data2" : "abcd",
      "sharedWithEmail" : "1@gmail.com",
      "userMail" : "user2@gmail.com"
    },
    "-Kb5sddvfgscWdDC9utF" : {
      "data1" : 3,
      "data2" : "abcd",
      "sharedWithEmail" : "b2@gmail.com",
      "userMail" : "user2@gmail.com"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your current structure you *can* test whether a user has access to a specific post because it was shared with their email:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "root_node": {
      "$uid": {
        "$postid": {
          ".read": "auth.token.email === child('sharedWithEmail').val()"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But with this structure it is impossible to test whether a user has access to all posts of a specific user, since you cannot *search* for a node under the path where you define security rules.

Comment: Thanks Frank for you answer, so can you suggest me what structure can I use to achieve this functionality where  only owner is allowed to write and read and user with mail in 'sharedWithEmail' key is also able to read.

Comment: That's what this answer shows. If it isn't what you want, describe the problem with different words please. Or better yet: show the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): what write operation should succeed and what operation should fail?

Comment: My application has feature to share an item with anyone by providing his mail id. At the same time I would also like the person who has shared it should have access to this item. Now, please suggest me how can I achieve this behavior. Thanks a lot for your efforts.

Comment: That's what the rules in my answer accomplish, don't the? Did you try them? What operation gave the unwanted result?

Comment: This doesn't seems to be working, if you have any alternative solution then please let me know.